# Details asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to open the details of the "Ansatte" object. The problem is that the Int parameter is only null

I have this View

```
@model IEnumerable<EL4.Administrasjon.Models.Ansatte>
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr data-pkey="@item.IdBaksystem">        
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnsNavn)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ePostAdresse)
    </td>        

    <td class="rowControl hidden">
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID_Ansatt }) |                
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

Then I have this in the controller

```
 public class HMAnsatteController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /HMAnsatte/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HM_000_EL4Entities hmEnt = new HM_000_EL4Entities();

        List<Ansatte> HMansatte = hmEnt.Ansatte.ToList();

        return View(HMansatte);
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int? ansattNr)
    {
        if (ansattNr == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            Entities ent = new Entities();

            Ansatt el4Ansatt = ent.Ansatt.Where(a => a.AnsattNr == ansattNr).First();

            return View(el4Ansatt);
        }
    }

}
```

When I click details, the URL looks correct: `http://localhost:50009/HMansatte/Details/1`

But the int ansattNr is always "null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have this ...

```
public ActionResult Details(int? ansattNr)
```

and it should be this because of the dynamic object you are passing in the link

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
```

or change this instead ...

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { ansattNr=item.ID_Ansatt })
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. I just started out using MVC, comming from the WebForms world :)

Answer (score 0):

It the line where you are creating your action link, you are naming the parameter "id" but in your action method, you are calling it "ansattNr". Those names should be the same. Since the default routing is already set up for "id", I would just change the method signature of your action method to this:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
```

That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your passing an variable with a name of id into the controller (which your global.asax has mapped to the URL so it shows like it does) but your controller is looking for a variable with name `ansattNr`.

You can either change the name of the variable in your controller to `id` or you can change your Action link to `@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { ansattNr=item.ID_Ansatt })` but the second option will change the formatting on your URL.